# destroying a jPlayer instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to destroy this instance of jPlayer whenever the #exit_button is clicked.I tried many solutions, but none seem to work.

this is the media player I'm using on my web project. http://www.codebasehero.com/files/music-player-1.0.1/demo/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//same voice diff flow
$('#enter_button1').click(function(){$('#photoline_overlay1').slideDown('9000');
    $('#enter_button1').hide();

         var description = 'Lorem ipsum';

   $('#photoline_overlay1').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
            autoPlay:false, 
            description:description,
            jPlayer:{
                swfPath:'js/jquery-jplayer', //You need to override the default swf path any time the directory structure changes


            }
        });

});


$('#exit_button1').click(function(){$('#photoline_overlay1').slideUp('9000');
    $('#enter_button1').show();
            $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer( "destroy" );

});
```

Comment: @Grievoushead ~ for some reason this is not working for me, it's keeps adding an instance of Jplayer on top of the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this, it might help http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-destroy